# Requesting large amounts of Twitter API data, service or how-to?

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest, twitter

I'm writing a data-analysis service that requires requesting a *lot* of data from Twitter. We tried going with a third-party solution, but the cost was high and there were still restrictions. Here is an example of our data needs:

Once daily, we have a utility that needs to request:

User info, ie @johndoe
(see this Twitter response for needed data: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup)
User info for EACH of @johndoe's followers. Need info like #tweets, #followers, etc

We also need a way to find the total # of mentions/RTs where one of @johndoe's followers mentioned/RT'd @johndoe.

With Twitter's rate limiting/throttling, there is likely no way we can accomplish this using Twitter's APIs. Are there any other services or tactics for acquiring so much data?

The utility is written in PHP and needs to save to a MySQL database as well. Not sure if that is necessary info, but just making sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With Twitter's rate limiting/throttling, there is likely no way we can accomplish this using Twitter's APIs. Are there any other services or tactics for acquiring so much data?

Contact Twitter directly for your bulk needs, they have a reason to limit the free API.